# Compile a C/C++ Program and store standard output in a File via Python

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, file-handling

Let's say I have a C/C++ file named `userfile.c`.

Using Python, how can I invoke the local gcc compiler so that the file is compiled and an executable is made? More specifically, I would like to provide some input (stdin) via some file `input.txt` and I want to save the standard output into another file called `output.txt`. I saw some documentation that I will need to use subprocess, but I'm not sure how to call that and how to provide custom input.

Comment: You could use [SCons](http://www.scons.org/).

Comment: How does `input.txt` and `output.txt` relate to the program in `userfile.c`? Do you need to run the C executable after compilation?

Comment: @MathiasRav: Yes, I want to provide the data from input.txt as stdin for the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution will be as given below:

```
import subprocess

if subprocess.call(["gcc", "test.c"]) == 0:
    subprocess.call(["./a.out <input.txt >output.txt"], shell=True)
else: print "Compilation errors"
```

2 caveats:

1. I am hardcoding stuff. You may want to parameterize and all that.
2. Setting *shell* to *True*, is a security risk, per Python documentation.

Comment: This is not working in Windows, but works fine in Mac OS X. How can I make it run in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution (written for Python 3):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(
    ('gcc', '-O', 'a.out', 'userfile.c'),
    stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)

with open('input.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    subprocess.check_call(
        ('./a.out',),
        stdin=infile,
        stdout=outfile,
        universal_newlines=True)
```

The parameter `universal_newlines` makes `subprocess` use strings rather than bytes for input and output. If you want bytes rather than strings, open the files in binary mode and set `universal_newlines=False`.

On compile or run errors in the two programs, [`subprocess.CalledProcessError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) will be raised by `subprocess.check_call`.