# How to specify standard input file for SCons

Tags: python, scons

I have a C Program "add.c", an input file "input.txt". I wish to compile this program using SCons and store the standard output into a file called "output.txt". How do I achieve this using SCons build utility? How can I make a python script that does this work?

```
compute(input_source_code,input_file_for_input_source_code) {//generate output file}
```

I read the documentation for SCons and it talks about multiple input source files, but I am not able to understand how to specify inputs(stdin) for the compiled source files.

To clarify further - I am trying to build an online assignment grader using Python/Django. What I wish to accomplish for this specific task is:
Compile given C programs - feed all the C programs with some predefined input, then store the outputs generated from executing the C program into another file. If I understand correctly, SCons allows me to build/make a C program file, but how do I instruct SCons to fetch input from a specific file for a specific C program. That is the C program I am trying to build via SCons should fetch input from a specific file.

[Compile a C/C++ Program and store standard output in a File via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240011/compile-a-c-c-program-and-store-standard-output-in-a-file-via-python)
One of the answers here by Sam Noir addresses my query but it works only in Mac/Linux but does not work in Windows - that is why I'm trying to use SCons build utility to accomplish this task.

Just thought I could add an example:

C file (add.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a,b;
scanf("%d", &a);
scanf("%d", &b);
printf("%d", a+b);
return 0;
}
```

input.txt:

```
3 7
```

Python script:

```
BUILD(add.c - fetch the required input from input.txt) and 
store the output into another file output.txt
```

(so it should be printing 10 in the output.txt).

So basically I want to use SCons to build and run the file add.c and generate output.txt by ensuring that whatever input is required for add.c is fetched from input.txt.

Comment: ?! Couldn't understand your question. You wish to write a program that produces output, build it using Scons, and then redirect the output to a file? You wish to redirect the output of Scons itself? Of the compiler? I'm lost.

Comment: It would also be interesting to know which parts of the SCons documentation you've read and are referring to.

Comment: Further, this question seems to be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240011/compile-a-c-c-program-and-store-standard-output-in-a-file-via-python , is it? If yes, you complain there that one of the provided solutions doesn't work under Windows. Is this a requirement for this question/task too? Then please say so in your question...you have to make constraints like these clear beforehand, and not after someone tried to answer.

Comment: @AmiTavory: I wish to write a Python script that compiles a C program, builds it - feeds it an input from another file and generates an output. The C program needs to fetch input from an input file. I am trying to build an online programming assignment grader like SPOJ.com.

Comment: @dirkbaechle: I've read the first six chapters. They are talking about using multiple "C" source files, but what I am interested in is - given a C source file, how do I make sure it uses input from another file? To clarify, the docs say that input for SCons is C Program, but I want to specify input for the C Program which is being built using SCons.

Comment: @dirkbaechle: Yes, this is related to that question, and one of the solutions does not work under Windows which is why I am considering SCons! I have updated the question description.

Comment: @dirkbaechle I have added an example, please check it.

Answer (score 2):

For your given example you could try something like:

```
env = Environment()
# Build the program and store a reference to it
prog = env.Program("cl_add", "add.c")
# Create a Command to run, relies on shell redirection
out = env.Command('output.txt','input.txt','%s < $SOURCE > $TARGET' % str(prog[0]))
# Let the Command depend on the Program created above
env.Depends(out, prog)
```

in your SConstruct. See also the UserGuide at http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html , Chap. 19. "Not Writing a Builder: the Command Builder".